# JCrop adding height and width to an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using JCrop to crop photos (obviously) and my issue is that I have the image clickable (launches a modal) and the width and height are different than what I have set for the image that is clicked on.

An example is:

```
$("#avatar-photo").html("<img src='" + replace + "' alt='Avatar' class='w3-center w3-round w3-border' style='height: 280px; width: 400px;' id='enlarged-photo'>
```

but when it loads in the modal, JCrop adds an inline style of this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="w3-center w3-round w3-border" style="height: 152px; width: 152px; display: none; visibility: hidden;" id="enlarged-photo">
```

Is there anyway to prevent JCrop from doing this, as it is making the image too small in the modal.

I hope that explains my issue.

Thanks!

update:

I've isolated the image sizing issue to this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="w3-center w3-round w3-border" style="height: 150px; width: 150px; display: block; visibility: visible; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;">
```

My only question is now is how to stop JCrop from putting a height and width for the style?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be because the codes are manipulating each other.

IN your JS:

```
style='height: 280px; width: 400px;'
```

IN your HTML:

```
style="height: 152px; width: 152px;
```

There both trying to value the image at a height and width. Remove one of them.

Comment: I can't remove the one JCrop is putting in automatically (I don't know where it is doing it) 

JCrop is automatically inserting this - style="height: 152px; width: 152px;" I would like to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it, it was a boxWidth and boxHeight issue